# VisualStudio 2019 Upgrade - compile errors with contant strings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

following code snippets compiled well with VS2012:

```
// define a common name
#define ID_BRIGHTNESS           "id_brightness"
#define ID_CONTRAST             "id_contrast"

...

// construct a XML structure

static char xmltempl[]={"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\
<param text=\"Brightness\">\
 <name>"ID_BRIGHTNESS"</name>\
</param>\
<param text=\"Contrast\">\
 <name>"ID_CONTRAST"</name>\
</param>\
...
```

This now fails with VS2019 with following error:

```
error C3680: cannot concatenate user-defined string literals with mismatched literal suffix identifiers
message : Concatenating suffix 'ID_BRIGHTNESS' with suffix 'ID_CONTRAST'
```

What exactly is going on here? Why can't I used these defines any more? Or better question: what do I have to do to let the compiler concatenate these static structures which make use of static defines?

Thanks!

Comment: [GCC gives a better error message](https://godbolt.org/z/3649oY), telling exactly what needs to be done to fix the error.

Comment: Add a space before and after the defined names.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, I would appreciate it if you could write them as answer and mark them. Because this will be beneficial to other community.